# How do you check if it is monday and after 9 o'clock javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have an alert run only when it is a certain day **AND** it is after 9am but i cant work out how to do it, here is the code i already have:

```
var today = new Date().getHours();
var date = new Date();
if (today >= 9) {
    if(today.getDay() == 3) {
        alert('Alert 1');
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You need `date.getDay()` and not `today.getDay()`. And btw: Monday is 1, not 3! And your code is missing the closing `}`.

Answer (score 3):

First, create an instance of the built-in class `Date`, then extract the current day and hours:

```js
const now = new Date();
var day = now.getDay();
var hours = now.getHours();
```

Now you can check if it's Monday and after 9am:

```js
if (day == 1 && hours >= 9) {
    console.log("Yes");
} else {
    console.log("No");
}
```

Notes:

- The `day` is an integer ranging from 0 to 6, 0 being Sunday and 6 being Saturday.
- The `hours` is an integer ranging from 0 to 23.